# function "scale" was previously not declared constexpr

Tags: c++, constexpr

I tried to compile (on VS15) example of constexpr functions from Stroustrup's book "Principles and practice using C++" second edition. And I get the error I mentioned in the title. All the code is from the book except for the struct Point.

```
struct Point {
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    Point(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y){}
};
constexpr double xscale = 10;   // scalling factors
constexpr double yscale = 0.8;

constexpr Point scale(Point p) { return{ xscale*p.x,yscale*p.y }; };

void user(Point p1)
{
    Point p2{ 10,10 };
    Point p3 = scale(p1);   // OK: p3=={100,8}; run-time evaluation si fine
    Point p4 = scale(p2);   // p4 == {100,8}

    constexpr Point p5 = scale(p1); // error: scale(p1) is not a constant
                                    // expression
    constexpr Point p6 = scale(p2); // p6=={100,8}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't include header which declare `scale` function (without `constexpr`)?

Comment: (Full) error message should even points to the previous (problematic) declaration.

Comment: @Jarod42 I literally didn’t include any headers in my source file. VS15 only marked the constexpr keyword before the function name.

Comment: BTW, p6 should have sameerror than `p5`, `p2` is not marked `constexpr`.

Comment: Yes, and I am convinced that initializing p6 is a mistake. But again, I find it strange that Stroustrup made such mistakes both in the code and in the comments.

Comment: In addition to Jarod's answer which is the likely cause of your issue, you should note that in general `constexpr` is a liar, so you shouldn't worry too much anyway. For example, in your code `p2` is not a constant expression, so other than you assume, p6 is not evaluated as `{100,8}` (other than by "accdient" because the optimizer does it anyway, but then it would do without `constexpr`, too). Yes, `constexpr` is a liar, did I mention that? It's a _can be, maybe_ thing. And, sadly, that sometimes is not what one thinks or wishes for.

Comment: @Xeron: I think the typo is the missing `constexpr` for `p2`, then comments are correct (assuming `p1` value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `Point` cannot be returned by constexpr scale as it doesn't have any `constexpr` constructor.

So it should be:

```
struct Point {
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    constexpr Point(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y){}
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xvSu1V)

Comment: yes, it finally works! But it should only be added that `p2` must be declared as `constexpr`.